# How to use kCIInputBoostShadowAmountKey?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to boost the shadows in an UIImage, akin to the one in Mac OS:

[image]

Is kCIInputBoostShadowAmountKey the correct key to use?

If yes, how to use it?

I'm able to use CIFilter with CIColorControls to edit the saturation and brightness:

```
CIContext *context3 = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
[filter setValue:outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:@0.3f forKey:kCIInputSaturationKey];
//[filter setValue:@1.0f forKey:kCIInputBoostShadowAmountKey]; this is not working.. since it's not in CIColorControls...
CIImage *outputImage3 = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
_outputImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context3 createCGImage:outputImage3 fromRect:outputImage3.extent]];
```

Update:

Got it it's **CIHighlightShadowAdjust**. But which parameter to set?

```
CIImage *inputImage;
NSNumber *inputRadius;
NSNumber *inputShadowAmount; // this one?
NSNumber *inputHighlightAmount;
NSNumber *_inputRadius;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the **key** too. Somehow there isn't, but you can use the string "inputHighlightAmount" directly.

```
let parameters = [
        kCIInputImageKey: self,
        "inputHighlightAmount": highlight,
        "inputShadowAmount": shadow,
        ] as [String : Any]
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIHighlightShadowAdjust", parameters: parameters)
```